# How to create new variables in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with these variables:

name, gdp, mort, latitude

```
        name        gdp       mort latitude
1    Algeria  4402.8190  78.200000   0.3111
2     Angola  2368.4710 280.000000   0.1367
3  Argentina  9228.0230  68.899990   0.3778
4  Australia 19930.3600   8.549999   0.3000
5    Bahamas 10829.1800  85.000000   0.2683
6 Bangladesh   972.6265  71.410000   0.2667
```

Data :

```
data <- structure(list(name = c("Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", 
    "Australia", 
    "Bahamas", "Bangladesh"), gdp = c(4402.819, 2368.471, 9228.023, 
    19930.36, 10829.18, 972.6265), mort = c(78.2, 280, 68.89999, 
    8.549999, 85, 71.41), latitude = c(0.3111, 0.1367, 0.3778, 0.3, 
    0.2683, 0.2667)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The question is :

Construct two new variables based on "mort" and "latitude":

- high_mortality = 1 if mort is greater than or equal to the median for mortality and high_mortality = 0 otherwise
- close_equator = 1 if latitude is less than or equal to the median for latitude and close_equator = 0 otherwise

How do I do this? I am a beginner at R.

Comment: Please put `dput(head(data))` as a code chunck inside the text of the post, instead of an image of it.

Comment: Hey I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I edited it in the post. Could you let me know if it's okay now? Thank you

Comment: thanks : much easier to help with usable data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R:

```
data$high_mortality <- as.numeric(data$mor >= median(data$mort))
data$close_equator  <- as.numeric(data$latitude <= median(data$latitude))
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(high_mortality = as.numeric(mort >= median(mort)),
              close_equator = as.numeric(latitude <= median(latitude)))

        name        gdp       mort latitude high_mortality close_equator
1    Algeria  4402.8190  78.200000   0.3111              1             0
2     Angola  2368.4710 280.000000   0.1367              1             1
3  Argentina  9228.0230  68.899990   0.3778              0             0
4  Australia 19930.3600   8.549999   0.3000              0             0
5    Bahamas 10829.1800  85.000000   0.2683              1             1
6 Bangladesh   972.6265  71.410000   0.2667              0             1
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your help! But for some reason it's saying "Error in df$mor : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" and "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function".

Comment: instead of `df`use your `data`, see my edit.

Comment: Whoah it works! You're such a pro. Thank you so much! Btw how do we make it 1 and 0 instead of True and False?

Comment: You could use `as.numeric`. Note that `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0` and can be added : `TRUE + TRUE == 2`

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` the solution, one of the multiple advantages is that you don't need `$` to call your variable. `?data.table` to further details about this package.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, high_mortality := ifelse(mort >= median(mort), 1, 0)]
data[, close_equator := ifelse(latitude <= median(latitude), 1, 0)]
data

         name        gdp       mort latitude high_mortality close_equator
1:    Algeria  4402.8190  78.200000   0.3111              1             0
2:     Angola  2368.4710 280.000000   0.1367              1             1
3:  Argentina  9228.0230  68.899990   0.3778              0             0
4:  Australia 19930.3600   8.549999   0.3000              0             0
5:    Bahamas 10829.1800  85.000000   0.2683              1             1
6: Bangladesh   972.6265  71.410000   0.2667              0             1
```